# How to re-enable default action after preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application where some actions are taking place on click event of buttons. Also, I want to append a query string on every  in the app. For this, I have written a jquery code, which is as follows:-

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = event.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href && href.indexOf('http') !== -1) {
      timezone = jstz.determine()
      window.location.href = href + '?jstz=' + timezone.name();
    }
    else 
    {
      // re-enable default;
    }
}, false);
```

The code prevents the default action of every click event. Then checks if the event generator has href attribute. If it has href attribute, then it appends the current client timezone in the url.

The problem is, the above code prevents the click event of every clickable object.

- How can I re-enable the default action?
- Is there any way by which I can use `event.preventDefault()` for only anchor tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement you logic with event listener on a jquery selector as:

```
$("#target").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = event.target.getAttribute("href");
  // blah blah
});
```

This way, for this example, prevent default is called only if the *element* with `id` target is **clicked**.

For more on jquery selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp